# Icecast stream to text using google cloud APIi

Tags: python, api, cloud, icecast

Hi I'm trying to write some code probably in Python orJavascript to capture an audio stream from an icecast server. The ice cast stream is a community based project ham radio operators and what they transmit and I would like it to be converted to text.
I've been looking through the API at Google Cloud. There are some good examples there of how to catch an audio stream from a microphone but cant see a way to use an an actual stream as a source.
I'm not too bad at packing already written code but to write something from scratch I don't think I have the ability could anyone point me in the right direction please

I was looking at this code and the documentation but only see microphone as a source.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

Comment: I'm actually in the process of building a similar project.  Let me know if you're interested.  brad@audiopump.co  KC9FQJ